# Tensorflow: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'train'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

> I am following a deep learning course, I get this error when I try to run my >code:'AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'train'
> I have a feeling it is a tensorflow version handling issue -& the fact of my limited knowledge >about it at the moment. I would like some help on how I can clean this up and have a smooth >running algorithm
> Here is my import before my actual algorithm

````
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior() 
#deprecated - from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
mnist = tfds.load('mnist')
#depricated - mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot = True, with_info=True, as_supervised=True)```

input_size = 784
output_size = 10
hidden_layer_size = 50

#Clear memory of variables from previous runs
#depricated - tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
#tf.disable_v2_behavior() 

#Declare the placeholders
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_size])
targets = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, output_size])

#Declare the weights and biases
weights_1 = tf.get_variable("weights_1", [input_size,hidden_layer_size])
biases_1 = tf.get_variable("biases_1", [hidden_layer_size])
#Declare the output nodes for the 1st hidden layer using the desired activation function
outputs_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs,weights_1) + biases_1)

#Declare the weights and biases for the second hidden layer
weights_2 = tf.get_variable("weights_2", [hidden_layer_size, hidden_layer_size])
biases_2 = tf.get_variable("biases_2", [hidden_layer_size])
#Declare the output nodes for hidden layer_2
outputs_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(outputs_1, weights_2) + biases_2)

#Declare the weights & biases for the output layer
weights_3 = tf.get_variable("weights_3", [hidden_layer_size,output_size])
biases_3 = tf.get_variable("biases_3", [output_size])
#Declare the final output nodes (nb: you can add a transformation final output with a desired 
optimizer)
outputs = tf.matmul(outputs_2, weights_3) + biases_3

#Next we need an activation function - we'll use the softmax activation with logits - the 
values b4 the activation occurs
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=outputs, labels=targets)
#we'll use the mean loss function as that give great performance boost to our algorithm
mean_loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

#Next, let's choose out optimization algorithm
optimize = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(mean_loss)

# Let's measure the accuracy of our model - using tf.argmax - which returns the index of the 
largest value
out_equals_target = tf.equal(tf.argmax(outputs,1),tf.argmax(targets,1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(out_equals_target, tf.float32))

#Now, let's set early stopping & Batching Mechanisms
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
initializer = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(initializer)

batch_size = 100
# batches = #samples/batch_size
batches_number = mnist.train._num_examples // batch_size

#Create the optimization

for epoch_counter in range(max_epochs):
    curr_epoch_loss = 0.
    for batch_counter in range(batches_number):
        input_batch, target_batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
    
        _, batch_loss = sess.run([optimize, mean_loss],
                                feed_dict = {inputs: input_batch, targets: target_batch})
        curr_epoch_loss += batch_loss
    #Let's set the avg. loss over all batches - n.b: its outside the batches for loop
    curr_epoch_loss /= batches_number

#The validation loss
input_batch, target_batch = mnist.validation.next_batch(mnist.validation._num_examples)
validation_loss, validation_accuracy = sess.run([mean_loss,accuracy],
                                                feed_dict={inputs: input_batch, target: 
target_batch})

#Finally print the results you've obtained - n.b: inside for loop
    print('Epoch' + str(epoch_counter + 1) + '_ Training loss: ' + 
'(0:.3f)'.format(curr_epoch_loss)+
          '_ Validation loss: ' + '(0:.3f)'.format(validation_loss) + 
          '_ Validation accuracy: ' + '(0:.2f)'.format(validation_accuracy * 100.) + '%')
# Add early stopping mechanism related to the early stop

if validation_loss > prev_validation_loss:
    break
prev_validation_loss = validation_loss
    print('End of training.')
````

Comment: Hi Alusine, welcome to the community. I reckon the error gets thrown at the `mnist.train._num_examples` part in the code, but can you please share the whole error message, including line numbers etc. for us to help better?

Comment: Hi Merve, thanks for your prompt response; here's the error code: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-7aab5166f997> in <module>
     70 
     71 # Calculate the number of batches per epoch for the training set.
---> 72 batches_number = mnist.train._num_examples // batch_size
     73 
     74 # Basic early stopping. Set a miximum number of epochs.

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'train'`

Comment: Seems some versioning issue to me. Are you referring to any tutorial/post for above code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the error by loading the dataset in a different way as below (code [ref](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview)).

```
ds, info = tfds.load('mnist', with_info=True)
# instead of...
# batches_number = mnist.train._num_examples // batch_size
batches_number = info.splits['train'].num_examples // batch_size
```

However, my best guess is that your program would crash again at `mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)` this time mainly because you don't/can't use the below call.

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot = True, with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
```

Features and functionalities of the dataset such as *.train*, *.validation*, *.next_batch* are related to that call in TF-1, and TF-2 to 1 bridges do not seem to enable the usage of that. Please refer [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32790#issuecomment-548700004) for more information.

You can either directly use TF-1.x or update your code to work with the new version of TF. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/splits) for dataset usage in TF-2 or [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data) for the Keras version.

Overall, I'd highly recommend to start your journey with the newest version of TF especially if you're still at the start of it.